# Is it possible to convert a Rcpp::List to std::vector?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

I would like to use a Rcpp::List in a parallel code. Rcpp::List are not thread safe. Is it possible to convert a Rcpp::List to a std::vector or another C++ object?

For example, I would like to convert a Rcpp::List which has, as first element, a NumericMatrix and has, as second element, a NumericVector, to a std::vector. Is it possible?

I am expecting a yes/no answer or a simple example.

Comment: First off, `std::vector<T>` is *also* not thread safe. Secondly, `Rcpp::List` is a heterogeneous container. `std::vector<T>` is type-homogeneous. Of course you could use a `std::vector<std::variant<MatrixType, std::vector<double>>>` (or `std::vector<std::any>` to circumvent this. But I would instead use a struct (or `std::tuple<>`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph what about an `std::vector<SEXP>`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, or that. But then it’s even less clear why one would convert from `Rcpp::List` to `std::vector<SEXP>`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, and as you say, the thread safety would still need to be addressed in either case.